# Why require return boolean value in Lua(cocos2d-x)

Tags: module, lua, cocos2d-x

I print `require("Square")` but It return `true` and I got an `attempt to index local 'r'` error, why it doesn't return a `cc.Scene`??
How do deal with this?

Square.lua

```
require "Cocos2d"
require "Cocos2dConstants"

local Square = class("Square",function()
    return cc.Scene:create()
end)

function Square.create()
    local square = Square.new()

    return square
end
function Square:ctor()
    self.visibleSize = cc.Director:getInstance():getVisibleSize()
    self.x = cc.Director:getInstance():getVisibleOrigin().x
    self.y = cc.Director:getInstance():getVisibleOrigin().y
    self.schedulerID = nil
end
```

call Square.lua in other file

```
local r = require("Square")
local square = r.create()
print("square = "..string.format("%s",square))
```

Comment: You need to `return Square` at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either return the module table at the bottom of the file:

```
return Square
```

Or use assign the module table directly into `package.loaded`:

```
package.loaded[...] = M
```

The first one looks more clear, in my opinion.